# Illustrator 3D Extrude Pipe Elbow

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I'm trying to create a 3D extrude of an ABS pipe elbow like this:

[image: Example image]

[Large image](http://www.solidshack.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/PVC-1.25in-Elbow-90deg-SxS.JPG).

Although it can be solid, isn't necessary for a hollow pipe.

I created a doughnut from two ellipses (one deleted from the other), then took a quarter of that ellipse (the elbow) and extruded--it looks similar, but it's edges are straight not rounded. I realize I could just create the same look with the pen and mesh gradients, but I'm going to be using the pipe elbow numerous times and at different angles, so I figure this is the quickest way to a reusable object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually easier than you think :)

Start with a circle shape, then go to 3D -> Revolve.

[image: I love donut]

Turn on preview checkbox, play with the options. You'd start with a full donut first. Adjust the Angle amount. you can also play with the Offset.

Comment: Very nice. I was playing around with Revolve, but I swear my object didn't look like this! I'll have to go back. Thank you for the quality print-screen answer.

Comment: Good tip with revolve options, I used it in my work, Thank You!
Peace :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select the correct edge. Each one will have a different outcome.